# How to show the employess who have only one project, and also their project. Many to Many relationship problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, many-to-many

Project Table:

[image: This is Project Table]

Employee Table

[image: This Is Employee Table]

Connector Table:

[image: This is many to many connector Table]

---

1. Therea are 6 employees who have only one project
2. one of the prjects is P2, it has 5 employees
3. and the other project is P3 which has 1 employee

---

```
   Select * from Emp
    Select * from Project
    Select * from PrEmpConnector
    ------------------------------------------------
    Select t.EmpId as Employee_Id, t.Project_Name
    from (  
    Select 
    PE.EmpId,
    P.Project_Name
    from PrEmpConnector as PE
    inner join Project as P on P.Id in( 
        Select sum(t.ProjectId)
        from PrEmpConnector as t
        group by t.EmpId
        having COUNT(t.EmpId) = 1
    )
    ) as t
    group by t.Project_Name, t.EmpId
    having t.EmpId in (
        Select t.EmpId
        from PrEmpConnector as t
        group by t.EmpId
        having COUNT(*) = 1
    )
```

Comment: Do you have question here? If so, what is it? What about your attempt(s) didn't work? Also, please don't post images of data, it really doesn't help us help you. Take the time to post tabuluar formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
select emp.name,emp.surname,project.project_name from 
PrEmpConnector 
inner join emp on emp.id=PrEmpConnector.emp_id
inner join Project on Project.id=PrEmpConnector.projectid
where emp.empid in (
select emp_id from PrEmpConnector
group by emp_id having count(projectid) =1)
```

Comment: Gabriel Durac Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for employees that only work on one project, you can join the three tables, aggregate by employee, and filter on groups that contain only one record with a `having` clause:

```
select 
    e.id employee_id, 
    e.name employee_name, 
    min(p.id) project_id, 
    min(p.project_name) project_name
from project p
inner join connector c on c.projectId = p.id
inner join employee e  on e.id = c.employeeId
group by e.id, e.name
having count(*) = 1
```